# blenderproc quickstart -- urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Tags: python

I am getting this error in Ubuntu 22.04 which I believe in part is very related to Blender.

```
(blenderproc) mona@ada:~/BlenderProc$ blenderproc quickstart
Warning: Changed install path from /home_local/mona... to /home/mona..., there is no /home_local/ on this machine.
Downloading blender from https://download.blender.org/release/Blender3.5/blender-3.5.1-linux-x64.tar.xz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mona/anaconda3/envs/blenderproc/bin/blenderproc", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('blenderproc', 'console_scripts', 'blenderproc')())
  File "/home/mona/BlenderProc/blenderproc/command_line.py", line 136, in cli
    blender_run_path, major_version = InstallUtility.make_sure_blender_is_installed(custom_blender_path,
  File "/home/mona/BlenderProc/blenderproc/python/utility/InstallUtility.py", line 168, in make_sure_blender_is_installed
    raise e
  File "/home/mona/BlenderProc/blenderproc/python/utility/InstallUtility.py", line 152, in make_sure_blender_is_installed
    file_tmp = urlretrieve(url, None, DownloadProgressBar())[0]
  File "/home/mona/anaconda3/envs/blenderproc/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 241, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "/home/mona/anaconda3/envs/blenderproc/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 216, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/home/mona/anaconda3/envs/blenderproc/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/home/mona/anaconda3/envs/blenderproc/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 634, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "/home/mona/anaconda3/envs/blenderproc/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 563, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/home/mona/anaconda3/envs/blenderproc/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/home/mona/anaconda3/envs/blenderproc/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 643, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Could you please look at [it](https://github.com/DLR-RM/BlenderProc/issues/1017) and guide me?

```
(base) mona@ada:~$ uname -a
Linux ada 6.2.0-37-generic #38~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Nov  2 18:01:13 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
(base) mona@ada:~$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

My current installed blender version is 3.0.1

Answer (score 1):

You could point it to your own location of Blender:

`(blenderproc) mona@ada:~/BlenderProc$ blenderproc quickstart --custom-blender-path ~/Downloads/blender-3.5.1-linux-x64`

`(blenderproc) mona@ada:~/BlenderProc$ blenderproc run ./blenderproc/scripts/quickstart.py --custom-blender-path ~/Downloads/blender-3.5.1-linux-x64`

Comment: Bit of a mystery to me why 'Forbidden' is returned from the url.. I can call it directly from my browser OK..

Comment: @RobinBetts did you get this error when you tried the command in OP too? It seems a few other users are getting same error and they have made a PR for it which is not yet merged.

Comment: No, I didn't install blenderproc.. (strictly, this is 3rd-party and off-topic here, but your quick answer snuck through :)  ) . I did manage to `curl` it OK, too.. so maybe it's a faulty wrap of a more primitive function.